# Prove $\frac{8}{3}\leqq c< 4$ for $a\geqq b> 0$ and $3\,a+ 2\,b- 6= ac+ 4\,b- 8= 0$ .

Tags: proof-verification, inequality

Given positive real numbers $a,\,b$ such that $a\geqq b$ and $3\,a+ 2\,b- 6= ac+ 4\,b- 8= 0$. Prove
$$\frac{8}{3}\leqq c< 4$$
I have a solution, and I hope to see a nicer one(s), thanks a real lot! We have 2 following (in)equalities
$$a(3\,c- 8)= 4(a- b)- 4(3\,a+ 2\,b- 6)+ 3(ac+ 4\,b- 8)\geqq 0$$
$$3\,a(4- c)= 4\,b+ 4(3\,a+ 2\,b- 6)- 3(ac+ 4\,b- 8)> 0$$
*q.e.d*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the linear equations.

$$3a+2b-6=0$$

$$ca +4b -8 = 0$$

By cross-multiplication,

$$a = \frac{-16+24}{12-2c} = \frac{4}{6-c}\ , \ b = \frac{-6c+24}{12-2c}=\frac{12-3c}{6-c}$$

Now $a>0\implies \frac{4}{6-c}>0\implies {\color{blue}{c<6}}$

$b>0\implies12-3c>0 \text{ and } 6-c>0 \text{ or } 12-3c<0 \text{ and } 6-c<0$

But we already know that $c<6$. So $$12-3c>0\implies \color{red}{c<4}$$

Now $$a\ge b \implies\frac{4}{6-c}\ge\frac{12-3c}{6-c}\implies4\ge12-3c\implies \color{red}{c\ge\frac{8}{3}}$$

Thus,

> $$\frac{8}{3}\le c<4$$